# How to retrieve value of a field base of max date in group by clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this data:

```
| name | type | score |
+------+------+-------+
|  a   |   1  |  15   |
+------+------+-------+
|  b   |   2  |  12   |
+------+------+-------+
|  c   |   1  |  17   |
+------+------+-------+
```

Now I must create a query to get count of each type and name of student which recieve maximum score.
This is my query :

```
select name , count(*) as count ,score ,type 
group by type
```

and the result is:

```
| name | type | score |  count |
+------+------+-------+--------+
|  a   |   1  |  15   |   2    |
+------+------+-------+--------+
|  b   |   2  |  12   |   1    |
+------+------+-------+--------+
```

but I expect this result:

```
| name | type | score |  count |
+------+------+-------+--------+
|  c   |   1  |  17   |   2    |
+------+------+-------+--------+
|  b   |   2  |  12   |   1    |
+------+------+-------+--------+
```

Comment: Why not `c 1 17`?

Comment: it was my mistake in typing question. I correct it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT x.*
     , y.total 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT type
            , MAX(score) score
            , COUNT(1) total 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP 
           BY type
     ) y 
    ON y.type = x.type 
   AND y.score = x.score;
```